# Perforce client side pre-commit hook

Tags: perforce, pre-commit-hook

We are using perforce as a source control for Visual studio solution.
Working with P4 and P4V.
Is it possible to add client side pre-commit hook? for instance to ensure the word "debugger;" is not exist in *.js files.
Could find something in Google.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Perforce triggers can be used to enforce such a policy, but they run in the server, not client-side. So most sites that I'm aware of would enforce a rule such as the one you describe using a change-content trigger in the server.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html

It's not obvious from your question why you need to have a client-side hook. Is there some reason you don't want to use a change-content trigger?

Perhaps you might consider re-framing your workflow as a code review process, and implement policies like this in your code review tool of choice.

Comment: Thanks, the reason that I want it on client side is that I don;t want it to be pre commit hook on all developers but on specific group.

Comment: It would be easy enough to implement a server-side trigger which implements on a pre-commit hook only for specific users, since the user name is available with the changelist information.  My reason for wanting to implement a client-side pre-commit hook is different though, I want to have the ability to run checks on information that only the user's machine knows.  For example, a pre-commit check to ensure that the user tested the executable before checking in, or a pre-commit check that scans for files which are involved in the build but haven't been added to a changelist.

Comment: we have similar type of requirement. Any way to invoke make file before perforce submit on CLIENT

Answer (score 4):

One approach that you could use is a "Custom Tool":
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/custom_tools.html

Basically you would write a script that takes the changelist as an arg checks your condition on every file in your changelist and calls p4 commit  if it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Use latest `git-p4`. My patch for the hook `p4-pre-submit` is merged into Git's `next` branch.

The hook is a simple executable script which will stop the submit process to start up if the script exist with non-zero status. So `p4-pre-submit` hook is pretty safe without any side effect.

See https://github.com/git/git/blob/next/Documentation/git-p4.txt for details.

Please note `git-p4` is an independent python script. It's not dependent on any specific version of git. So you can upgrade `git-p4` only.

The hook `p4-pre-submit` has no other interaction with `git/git-p4` except exiting status. So you can write the hook in any language (I recommend python).

Here is sample `.git/hooks/p4-pre-submit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GIT_DIR && make test
```